# Adding picture to randomized list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding a button to a website that randomizes NBA teams and provides a picture with the answer. I have the randomizer set up to provide the random team when the button is pushed but I'm unsure how to get a picture to go along with the team selected.

My randomizer in JS:

```
let teams = 
    {
        atlanta: "Atlanta Hawks",
        boston: "Boston Celtics",
        brooklyn: "Brooklyn Nets",
        charlotte: "Charlotte Hornets",
        chicago: "Chicago Bulls",
        cleveland: "Cleveland Cavaliers",
        dallas: "Dallas Mavericks",
        denver: "Denver Nuggets",
        detroit: "Detroit Pistons",
        goldenState: "Golden State Warriors",
        houston: "Houston Rockets",
        indiana: "Indiana Pacers",
        clippers: "Los Angeles Clippers",
        lakers: "Los Angeles Lakers",
        memphis: "Memphis Grizzlies",
        miami: "Miami Heat",
        milwaukee: "Milwaukee Bucks",
        minnesota: "Minnesota Timberwolves",
        pelicans: "New Orleans Pelicans",
        knicks: "New York Knicks",
        thunder: "Oklahoma City Thunder",
        orlando: "Orlando Magic",
        philadelphia: "Philadelphia 76ers",
        phoenix: "Phoenix Suns",
        portland: "Portland Trail Blazers",
        sacramento: "Sacramento Kings",
        spurs: "San Antonio Spurs",
        toronto: "Toronto Raptors",
        utah: "Utah Jazz",
        washington: "Washington Wizards"
    }

const values = Object.values(teams)

app.get("/api/teams", (req, res)=>{
    const randomTeam = values[Math.floor(Math.random()*values.length)]
    console.log(randomTeam)
    res.status(200).send(randomTeam)
})
```

To add team name to HTML:

```
<script>
      document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
        axios.get("http://localhost:5151/api/teams").then(function(response) {
            const data = response.data;
            document.getElementById("randomTeamCard").innerHTML = [data].map(function(team) {
                return `The team you should bandwagon is: ${data}!`;
              })
              .join("");
          }).catch(function (err) {
            document.getElementById("randomTeamCard").innerHTML =
              '<li class="text-danger">' + err.message + "</li>";
          });
      };
    </script>
```

Comment: One way is to change your json to be like `let teams = [{id: 'atlanta', name: 'Atlanta Hawrks`, pictureUrl: 'https....pepe.png'} , {id: 'atlanta2', name: 'Atlanta Hawrks2`, pictureUrl: 'https....pepe2.png'}];`. In this way, each object in our array has the id, the actual name, and the url to the picture you wish to load. Just loop throughout the objects to obtain the information you need.